# Buddhism in ancient Arabic regions

Tags: theravada, history

In the age of king "Asoka", the expansion of Buddhism reached Arabic countries. Does anybody know what those countries are called now?

Can anyone provide details about what happened to those places / Temples ?

Comment: See also [Buddhism in the Middle East](http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/1621/254)

Comment: Very interesting question. Thanks for asking it.

Comment: Thank you.I got a good answer from "ChrisW" but a lot is still out there,like what happened to those places. @Lanka

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wikipedia's [Ashoka](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ashoka) article includes this map:

[image]

Its western border is the [Seleucid empire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seleucid_Empire) which appears to be where modern-day **Iran** is (note that Iran I think might be ethnically Persian rather than [Arabian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabs)).

It also includes modern-day countries like Pakistan and Afghanistan (which are Islamic but not exactly Arabic).

[This map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yona) is labelled "Buddhist proselytism at the time of king Ashoka (260–218 BCE)":

[image]

It shows Buddhist proselytism reaching (beyond the Maurya empire) to Alexandria (which is in modern-day Egypt), and Antioch (modern Turkey).

This may not be "expansion of Buddhism" though, it's more like "envoys from the Buddhist empire".

Comment: I agree, very nice. Good to see some historic background and thorough research.